# ¿Como publicar una actualización de una aplicación en Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Desarrollé una aplicación para el SO Android, pero ahora le he realizado unos cambios y quisiera saber cómo publico la nueva aplicación con dichos cambios.

Comment: Estoy seguro que este [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=es-419) de la documentación oficial de google te será útil...

Comment: La respuesta de @Elenasys está perfecta, no hay pierde :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu consola de desarrollo Google Play ve a **`ALL APLICATIONS`** (Androide), selecciona tu aplicación a actualizar, ve a la opción **`APK`** y puedes subirla a producción directamente y publicarla :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o probrar primero en **`ALPHA`** o **`BETA TESTING`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando este lista puedes promoverla a producción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mayor información ve a la documentación:

- **[Publicar una aplicación.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=es)**
- **[Actualización de aplicaciones](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=es-419).**